# How to get last measure even empty, depending dimensions, with SSAS

Tags: ssas, mdx, cube

I can't find a way to get a "snapshot" of data through a cube.

I have an inventory saved by date.
It looks like this:
[image: inventory]

My measure that shows inventory is called "Stock" and aggregation mode is "LastNonEmpty"

When I filter on a date, I always get the same result.

[image: Filter do nothing]

I understand why. But I can't find a formula for calculation measure and I'm not at ease with MDX queries.

Moreover, I correctly get a total of 8 on Week 39, but if I filter on the specific size "40", I will get a total of 1. This one is correctly excluded in total!

My aim is to have a snapshot of inventory that shows the last value including empty value and depending on other filters.
When I pick "Week 35" I want to have inventory on week 35. On week 38 I want to get an only value that exists. If I pick weeks from 35 to 38, I want the results of last week.

"week" is a hierarchy, there is detail until day under this hierarchy

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Last Ever Non empty by Chris Webb.